# Parse a variable as if it were a string literal

Tags: php, string

I have some string in a variable that I don't control.

`$foo = 'hey\nman';`

(notice the single quotes, it's a literal \n not the new line character)

Now I would like to have foo parsed as if it were inside a double quotes instead of single. So it would convert the literal escape characters to their corresponding ascii characters. All of then /r, /n, /b, /t, etc.

I have access to `$foo` but I can't change the code that assigns it's value to it. My option is a regex but that can get ugly with many number of different characters possible. I like how neatly php handles it and was wondering if I can leverage it.

Comment: `json_decode("'" + $foo + "'");` would work

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant this returns 0 for me

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant That looks like it will work! Let me check it out.

Comment: @Achshar: fix as it doesn't work ... ` json_decode("\"$foo\"");`

Comment: @Gavriel: In fact it was " and not ' that I had to use ... LOL

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I think that will fail if $foo contains quotes. Looking into it though.

Comment: @Achshar: yes, need to escape them :/

Comment: I might have to go with eval then :( edit: same problem with eval as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval:

```
$foo = 'hey\nman';
eval ('$b = "' . $foo . '";');
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: Yeah eval was another option but I felt nasty even thinking about it.

Comment: Had to go with this one after all because json_decode isn't very happy about new lines apparently. Had to add slashes though because foo can have quotes. `eval('$foo = "'.addcslashes($foo, '"').'";');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use string replace

```
$foo = str_replace('\n', "\n", $foo);
```

Comment: but he wants \b, \t, etc as well

Comment: I wrote about it in the question, regex is an option but it will get messy as more escaped characters are taken into account. I don't want to maintain an array of all the possible characters out there.